# Take unique URL code and place into PHP session

Tags: php, session, url, get, isset

I'm trying to retrieve a 'campaign' code from the URL when a user visits my site and use it in the page. This campaign code is then stored in a session for the rest of the pages visited, so it isn't lost should users look around the site. Of course, when users who visit don't have a 'campaign' code in the URL (say they come from Google), then I want to assign them a default code. I think I've grasped it with the following as it appears to work on my server but am unsure if it's too code heavy and/or a security risk.

```
<?php
session_start(); // starts the PHP session data

if ( isset( $_GET['campaign'] ) ) // check if there is a 'campaign' code in the URL as a variable
{
    $campaign = $_GET['campaign']; // first, if there is a 'campaign' code in the URL use that$campaign = 
}
elseif ( isset( $_SESSION['campaign'] ) ) // if no campaign code is in the URL but there is session data for the 'campaign' code use that - usually on other pages on the same server
{
    $campaign = $_SESSION['campaign'];
}
else // Otherwise, if no campaign code is either in the URL or session data, use the default 'campaign' code
{
    $campaign = "test1";
}

//save the 'campaign' value in a session
$_SESSION['campaign'] = $campaign; // store session data
?>
```

Then wherever I want to add the campaign code in the page, I will use:

```
<?php echo $campaign; ?>
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: With `if (!isset($_GET['campaign'])`, you're checking if the variable does **NOT** exist. Be careful :)

Comment: You are also adding ; after if conditions. Although this is not incorrect, it'll drive you to unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks, so would the following be better practice?

    `<?php`
    `session_start();` 
    `if (!isset($campaign)) {`
    `if ($campaign = $_GET['campaign']);` 
    `elseif ($campaign = $_SESSION['campaign']);`
    `else $campaign = "test1";` 
    `}`
    `$_SESSION['campaign'] = $campaign;`
    `?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what for you use this value later on. If you for example store your sessions in database and you have a field for that value also, then you will need to escape it first. Don't see any other possible risk from, that code.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to this site, so took me a while to realise you'd amended the code. Just tried it now and it works fine. I was looking at removing the 'isset' references altogether and that seemed to work too. Are there any implications with doing this? 
`<?php`
`session_start();`
`if ($campaign = $_GET['campaign']);`
`elseif ($campaign = $_SESSION['campaign']);`
`else $campaign = "test1";`
`$_SESSION['campaign'] = $campaign;`
`?>`

Comment: First of all what, that `if ($campaign = $_GET['campaign']);` is going to check. You could do like this `if ( $_GET['campaign'] )`, then you are checking, that there should be something in `$_GET['campaign']`, otherwise `if` will not be true. But this would be wrong also, since, you can't be 100% shure, that there will be index `campaign` in array `$_GET`. If not it will give you a warning or error. Don't remember for sure. Either way isset is the best way to check, that this index exists. Currently you are just assiging the value in if condition statement. http://www.youtube.com/v/WrjwaqZfjIY